# Hamburger Menu Disappears In Mobile View

Tags: html

I’m not a developer of any sort however, I manage some content for local non-profit lacrosse organization. The app/site support team says nothings wrong yet, the hamburger menu disappears depending on which url the end user goes to. For instance if you go to [www.nsyla.org](http://www.nsyla.org) from an iPhone you get the hamburger menu yet the [www.northsouthborough.demosphere-secure.com](http://www.northsouthborough.demosphere-secure.com) it’s gone! Since, the support team isn’t all that helpful I wanted to pose the question here if anyone could help me identify what the issue is. Here’s a side by side comparison [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uonYh.jpg)

I’ve reach out the support team and they’ve given me the runaround. I extracted the html for each site and compared them using MS Word and I don’t see any differences. I would like some help finding this issue so I can try to get the support team to actually fix it. In today society everyone is on their phone so, we need this accessible to everyone both on and off the phone.

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire a developer!  Might not be the answer you want, but this is definitely not the place for eliciting _ad hoc_ developer work.  Try Fiverr or Reddit.  The rules for asking questions here are quite strict.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.